# How can I convert a string converted using toLocaleString() in javascript back to Date Object?

Tags: javascript, function, date, object, google-apps-script

I am using the Javascript function toLocaleString() to convert date object into string (As it's output is very user friendly), for storage purpose, and then I want to fetch that saved data (obviously in the form of string) later, and I want to compare such to dates.

```
I have date stored in this format : February 5, 2016 7:04:40 PM IST
```

But That's not possible directly, so I tried to convert that string to date object using both implicit (using Date constructor) and explicit (Using Date Object) methods. But it gives Invalid date, as output, when printed.
   Then I google a lot to find out how can I convert date from this format directly back to the Date Object so that I can perform the desired date operations. But I couldn't found anything worth using. 
   Please help me to came out with a solution to that problem, so that I can complete my project.

Comment: I would recommend moment.js to work with dates. It proved very efficient for me.

Comment: Why do you need a "very user friendly" format for storage? (If by "storage" you mean in a database isn't it a date column?) You only need a user friendly format for what is displayed to the user - the rest of the time use whatever is easiest to work with in your code.

Comment: Juan, Thanks for the suggestion, actually, I am using Google App Script for my work, and I don't think that there we can use any javascript library, If I am wrong please let me know !

Comment: Hi nnnnnn, actually I am storing the data in a Spreadsheet using Google App Script, so I want that to be readable by anyone because at any time, I need to go through that spreadsheet, I can easily read that.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to store a date in a user friendly manner. You store the data that is needed to create a user friendly display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use pure javascript you should create a function which parses your string in order to use those arguments to create a date object.

```
var months = {
  'january': 0,
  'february': 1,
  'march': 2,
  'april': 3,
  'may': 4,
  'june': 5,
  'july': 6,
  'august': 7,
  'september': 8,
  'october': 9,
  'november': 10,
  'december': 11,
};

var strDate = "February 5, 2016 7:04:40 PM IST";

var parts = strDate.split(' ');
var year = parts[2];
var month = months[parts[0].toLowerCase()];
var day = parts[1].replace(/\,/g,"");

var timeParts = parts[3].split(':');
var hours = timeParts[0];
var minutes = timeParts[1];
var seconds = timeParts[2];

if (parts[4]==="PM") {
    hours = parseInt(hours) + 12;
}

var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
alert(d.toLocaleString());
```

In the futur please put a little more efforts into it. You could've easily written this yourself.

edit 2 : Actually none of this was needed. You can use the Date.parse() function as long if you remove the IST from the end.

```
var strDate = "February 5, 2016 7:04:40 PM";
var d = new Date("February 5, 2016 7:04:40 PM");
alert(d.toLocaleString());
```

Then if you want you can set the timezone manually.

Comment: Thanks phenxd for your answer,but I think that will take a lot of development time, I am looking for something quick and efficient, like a inbuilt function or function written by someone who has faced similar problem

Comment: @SKG StackOverflow is not for "Pleez gimme teh codez", it's to help you fix coding problems you have actually tried to solve

Comment: Yes Juan, I know that, but I am just asking for the simpler solution, which anyone has done, when he faced similar problem. Please Juan, please don't Downvote my question, this question is very important for me, I am am extreme beginner and I am looking for some help. Please I am requesting you not to do that. Infact you should upvote this so that other people can see and can solve their problem, like me.

Comment: Well, the thing is, it's not a bad thing for beginners to try and code things yourself. If you really need to use the JS Date object and it won't take your string, you need to parse it for it to work. In this case it might have been faster (and a better learning experience!) to code it yourself.

Comment: @SKG Sorry but I will always downvote questions that don't show enough effort, you have to at least give it a shot before you ask. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I also won't upvote this answer (though it works) because it may keep you from a learning experience

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Juan, I appreciate your work and effort towards stack overflow, thanks for guiding me.

Comment: Thank you very much phenxd, for helping me, I'll with go with your second option, I just needed something like that.Thanks for your support !!

Comment: One more thing Juan, I didn't wanted any code for my problem,but I only wanted any functionality or way supported by Javascript, that will solve my problem, and phexnxd has  given a very nice answer, I liked his edit 2: part because I was looking for something like that. Ok if you wish you can downvote, but I would suggest you to think a little bit more before doing this for other people, because, people doesn't come here to get the code of their problem, but to get insight of the way how they can solve their problem.

Comment: "*You can use the Date.parse() function…*". Noooo! Never do that, manual parsing is vastly superior. The output of *toLocaleString* is entirely implementation dependent and there is no requirement for browsers to parse their own output, much less that of other browsers (which almost certainly will have a different idea of what a "locale" date string looks like (for me, IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome all give different results).

Comment: Also, your parse function will create a date with an offset for the host system, which may not be IST, so it will represent a different instant in time.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using the Javascript function toLocaleString() to convert date object into string (As it's output is very user friendly), for storage purpose

That is not a good idea. You should store data in the best format for storage and present to users in the best format for humans. The two are often different.

> and then I want to fetch that saved data (obviously in the form of string) later, and I want to compare such to dates.

Far better to store the date in a format that your database supports natively, or as an ISO 8601 compliant string. There is no standard for time zone abbreviations, but I'll guess that IST is India Standard Time, which is +0530. The equivalent UTC ISO 8601 string is "2016-02-05T13:34:40Z", which can be created from your initial Date object using [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring).

Then, when you read from the database, convert to whatever format is required for use.

Most ECMAScript hosts will correctly parse "2016-02-06T13:34:40Z", however some will not. A simple parser that also validates the values is:

```js
function parseISO(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(b[0],--b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5],(b[6]?(b[6]+'000').slice(0,3):0)))
  return d && d.getUTCMonth() == b[1] && d.getUTCHours() == b[3] &&
         d.getUTCMinutes() == b[4]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

document.write(parseISO('2016-02-05T13:34:40Z').toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thanks RobG, for your answer, your effort really helped me. Thanks for such a  nice answer !